# How to make my laptop fan not running all the time on Low CPU Power

Tags: laptop, fan

Hello I Just Installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on My Hp 15db0015dx and the Fans runs almost all the time and I have check the CPU and GPU Usage and it low and it still is running. When I was on zorin os 16 I got my fans not to run all the time. I would like to do that on Ubuntu. and Yes I do have fan always on turned off in the BIOS.